# how to remove prefixes from projectes in hosted blazorwasm project

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I want to set up a hosted blazorwasm project via the dotnet cli using the following command

`dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted`

Say that i executed this command in a folder called test then all the projects inside this new solution will have the prefix `test.` in visual studio.

[image]

I want my project to not have these prefixes so i tried just renaming the projects in vs 2022 but this results in the following error.

[image]

How do i safely remove the prefixes from these project without crashing my builds?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change names of your projects, you can search and replace project name, then change project folder and project file. It works, I do this sometimes.

**Follow these Steps:**

1. Open your whole solution folder using `vscode`. Go to `search` tab and replace all occurence of that project name e.g. `test.Shared` to `NewProjectName`. Make sure that you match case and whole word.
2. Change the folder name for `test.Shared` to `NewProjectName`.
3. Change `test.Shared.csproj` inside that folder to `NewProjectName.csproj`.

After that you are done, compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the project solution (.sln) file:

```
Project("{...}") = "Server", "test\Server\test.Server.csproj", "{823DA873-9616-4245-AC45-B59535AA865B}"
EndProject
Project("{...}") = "Client", "test\Client\test.Client.csproj", "{30EBEA6F-3384-4EEF-ABCC-22954275A2AC}"
EndProject
Project("{...}") = "Shared", "test\Shared\test.Shared.csproj", "{3BEE92B9-A658-4825-B43F-10DB6850E60F}"
EndProject
```